# Emscripten (with pthread) POST http://localhost:8080/stdio.html 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: c, pthreads, emscripten

emcc 3.1.42-git

I have passed in "USE_PTHREADS=1" and "-pthread" compiler flags.
But still looks like ENVIRONMENT_IS_PTHREAD is undefined. (see code below)
I don't find stdio.html anywhere in the directory structure.

This if from the generated JS file::

```
 if (typeof window == "object" && (typeof ENVIRONMENT_IS_PTHREAD == "undefined" || !ENVIRONMENT_IS_PTHREAD)) 
{  
      blah blah  
      http.open("POST", "stdio.html", false); 
      blah blah 
}
```

What can I do about this error?